# Sugar daddy wants to transfer me money for me to buy him gift cards

Tags: banking, money-transfer, online-banking, sugar-daddy

I’ve been talking to a sugar daddy for a couple days and he wants to mobile transfer me 200$. He wants me to buy 150$ worth of google play gift cards for him and then keep 50$ for myself. Is this a scam?

Comment: yes this is scam. You can search this website for "gift cards" and find explanation of why it works

Comment: The way it works is the transfer of $200 will be fake or cancelled or revoked, so you will be spending your own $150. Why do you think he doesn't just buy his own gift cards with his own money?.

Comment: Indeed, why would he want the gift cards instead of the money?  (As an occasional recipient of gift cards, I have to say it's rather annoying to be given a gift card for something I wouldn't want to buy.)